# Did Nigel Farage ever explain why the UK should leave the EU?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, brexit

Some explanation is probably necessary...

I know he explained many times what he considered to be faults with the EU, but those are not reasons to leave - they are firstly things to be fixed, and only if you try and fail to fix the faults would you choose to leave, right?

Was there ever a time when Farage campaigned to fix any specific problems that he claimed were present in the EU?

Alternatively, did he ever explain why membership would be a bad thing *even in the absence of any faults*?

Or did he explain how the EU is a flawed concept that can never be a good thing to be a member of?

I would appreciate references if you have them.

Answer (score 11):

> **Was there ever a time when Farage campaigned to fix any specific problems that he claimed were present in the EU?**

In 2016 he was [quoted as saying](https://www.independent.co.uk/voices/eu-referendum-brexit-nigel-farage-on-why-you-should-vote-to-leave-a7091021.html)

> The EU cannot be reformed"

---

> **did he ever explain why membership would be a bad thing even in the absence of any faults?**

He claims

> The fact is that the European Union is a hopelessly outdated, stagnant, failed project. It is inwards looking in a global world, painfully ill-equipped to deal with the realities of the globalised world we now find ourselves in. Just look at how the EU has gone from one disaster to another, including a Eurozone crisis that has been the cause of huge amounts of human misery.

Unfortunately most politicians, especially populist politicians, do not regard it as their responsibility to provide answers on other people's terms.

Answer (score 3):

Here's three things he claimed that the EU does wrong

He claimed we should leave the EU because it would alter our immigration controls vs the EU

[image]

He also said that

[EU membership costs the UK £55 million every single day.](https://twitter.com/Nigel_Farage/status/704320293486108672)

Meaning this as a net figure, including positive flows

He also claimed that "[Outside EU we can have trade and co-operation with our European neighbours whilst negotiating our own trade deals globally. Win-win.](https://twitter.com/nigel_farage/status/691557168139534336)"

Meaning that if the UK negotiated it's own trade arrangements with other countries these would be more favourable than the current EU negotiated agreements with other countries

So, given in the opinion of Nigel Farrage these things are wrong, could they be fixed by reforming the EU?  No says Nigel

> The pro-Brexit politician said the European Union would not be able to
>   reform because it had lost its only opportunity to do so.
>
> Mr Farage said the EU had failed to "democratise" and create a
>   relationship with citizens, destroying its chances to be supported by
>   member states like the UK.
>
> He said: "If you listen to what is being said today by Juncker, by
>   Tajani from the European Parliament, by Tusk from the European
>   Council, and indeed Merkel, Macron – what they are all arguing for is
>   deeper centralisation.

( https://www.express.co.uk/news/uk/901691/Brexit-news-latest-UK-EU-European-Union-Nigel-Farage-Juncker-Brussels-reform-video )